# Import Unicode text into excel sheet from Web(html) source

Tags: excel, vba

I used this below mentioned code to fetch HTML source from websites. I have no problem fetching data which are in English. But if they are in any other language, i am unable to import that text without turning that text into gibberish.

How can I allow below code to import other language text in their actual form.

```
Sub test()
Dim FILENAME As String
Dim FileNum As Long

FILENAME = "C:\Temp\Source.txt"
FileNum = FreeFile


Open FILENAME For Output As FileNum
Print #FileNum, GetSource("https://www.pleasehelp.com/thankyou.html")
Close FileNum

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\TEMP\Source.txt", Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "Source"
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2)
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub

Function GetSource(sURL As String) As String
Dim oXHTTP As Object
Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXHTTP.send
GetSource = oXHTTP.responsetext
Set oXHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Stream object instead of the Open statement for output to a file.  The Stream object allows one to set the character set to unicode for translating the contents.  The following example specifically uses UTF-8 encoding.

Note that the code uses early binding, so you'll need to set a reference (`Visual Basic Editor >> Tools >> References`) to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x. Library`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim outFile As String
    outFile = "C:\Temp\Source.txt"

    Dim stream As ADODB.stream
    Set stream = New ADODB.stream
    With stream
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Mode = adModeReadWrite
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Open
        .WriteText GetSource("https://www.pleasehelp.com/thankyou.html")
        .SaveToFile outFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite 'overwrites any already existing file
        .Close
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & outFile, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "Source"
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2)
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you help Domenic.. I tried you code but since I don't much about VBA. I was still getting error. Could be i chose wrong ActiveX library. I just added .TextFilePlatform = 65001 under query table and replaced 'GetSource = oXHTTP.responsetext with
GetSource = StrConv(oXHTTP.responseBody, vbUnicode) in function and it worked..